# Memory issue with Ember

Tags: javascript, memory, ember.js

I'm trying to understand why my Ember application has currently memory issue.

Basically what happens is, when I load the application (Snapshot 1), I'm on the landing page, that's the default state of the app.

When I navigate from page to page, then going back to the landing page, it takes more memory. I continue to navigate to the same pages, and the memory increases again. If I'm using the application during a long time without refreshing the browser, the memory explodes.

It's not easy to read but it seems like there is something related to jQuery...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea what could generate those memory issue?

Thanks

Comment: Check the snapshots for Detached DOM Trees or DOM element wrapper objects highlighted in yellow or red. If you find any, follow the retaining tree back to a variable name that you recognise. Classic article: http://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/